# Ormlite Descending Index

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is it possible to define a descending index in OrmLite?  I can only see the `[Index]` attribute but I have a table of over 1 million records and need a descending index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's for a composite index you can specify it within its name:

```
[CompositeIndex("Field1", "Field2 DESC")]
public class Table
{
    ...
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise you can use a [Pre/Post Custom SQL Hooks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pre--post-custom-sql-hooks-when-creating-and-dropping-tables), e.g:

```
[PostCreateTable("CREATE INDEX IX_NAME ON MyTable (Field1 DESC);")]
public class MyTable
{
    ...
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Which will execute the Post SQL Hook to create the index after the table is created.